# Highstock 1.2.5 breaking change - tooltip not showing when "showInLegend" is false

Tags: highcharts

We recently upgraded from Highstock 1.2.4 to 1.2.5.

We have a series of 'notes' that simply show icons at various points in time. We've specified NOT to show this series in the legend. Using the old version (1.2.4) we are able to hover over the icon and view a tooltip. After switching to 1.2.5 we no longer see the tooltip. Is there configuration that can be changed to once again allow us to view tooltips for this series?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest to update to 1.3.0 version.

Comment: I've tried updating to 1.3.0 and am having trouble with line 650 of exporting.js (elem.onclick = elem.ontouchstart = null;)...still troubleshooting

Comment: It is possible to reproduce your example in jsfiddle.net /